# Why is my content going above my header?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

so this is just a section of my page, im confused as to why my content is going above and under my header when i set the header position to fixed?

```
Here is my code:
```

https://jsfiddle.net/CheckLife/nod19rze/2/

```
Here is a better picture of whats going on, its a screenshot:
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pl13v.jpg

Comment: your code is totally messed up. check all the opening and closing tags. Check how you used your `<a>` tag. `<a href="#" /> == this is wrong`. rewrite the code first, i guess that will fix it already

Comment: what do my a tags have to do with the position though? @lucian im just trying to figure out whats wrong with the display

Comment: your while code is inside header tag, so it's messed up. i have rearranged it but still i can't figure out what's exactly you're trying to do

Comment: @lucian I just explained that im trying to make the container where the paragraph is and everything else in it go UNDER my fixed header as it should.

Comment: @Lucian got it man thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for `absolute` and `fixed` position element, you'll need to use padding to take the space since these elements won't take any layout. in your case i suggest to use padding for container

```
.container {
  padding-top: 170px; //it should be more than or equal to header height
}
```

also i suggest to use higher z-index for header so that it will always be at the top.

```
.header {
  z-index: 9;
}
```

here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nod19rze/9/

Comment: ah ok thanks, yeah i get that. So are using either margin or padding to make the following container go under it? Or is than a more ethical approach?

Comment: i recommend using padding since if you use margin on the sibling before it, it's possible to be margin collapse issue. so use padding. and if this helped you, don't forget to upvote and mark it as answer.

Comment: alright, and not to sound repetitive but those are the best practices? @lucian Thanks again though

Comment: yeah, this is the best practices. on the modern browsers, there is no padding collapse issue but yet there is margin collapse issue. so follow it

Answer (score 0):

There is a `position: relative` given to the images, which means, the images will take a position relative of the closest parent element which has `position:absolute`.

It has nothing to do with `position: fixed` specified to the header.

Here's an example. https://jsfiddle.net/voaxhmu2/

The blue `div` is positioned relative to the red `div`. Therefore specifying `top: 30px; left:10px` will offset the blue `div` by 10 and 30 pixels from the position of the red `div`

You can either increase the values of the offsets to match your needs but that's not actually a good practice. Instead you can remove the `position: absolute` and `position: relative` and position them with bootstrap. It's much easier.

Comment: im not familiar with bootstrap yet @gowri ,so i should increase the top margin of the "container" class to make it equal to the header?

Comment: yeah thats what i want to happen @gowri . i know im a noob. but is there a safer practice than just using the margin to push the container down?

Comment: I did not edit anything neither add anything. All I did was correct your error. The correct syntax is `<a> </a>` Not `<a /> </a>` . Fixing that fixed your code.

Comment: thats how i them though? @gowri

Comment: No, here is your code, directly copy pasted without any edit.

`<a href="#kobesec"/>Kobe</a>`
`<a href="#"/>Kevin Durant</a>`
`<image src="nbaone.png" width="40px" height="55px" class="nba">`
`<a href="#"/>The Goat</a>`

And also image tags should be `<img attributes />` not `<img attributes >`

Answer (score 0):

I think you was trying to made a Fixed Top Menu. If that was the case. You could follow my code below. I have edited your code before.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

header,
nav,
section,
aside,
footer,
article {
  display: block;
}

body {
  background-image: url(backwood.png);
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.container {
  margin-top: 190px;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 1300px;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #5092f4, #f29641);
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
}

.header h1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #f4ca1f;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.tmacw {
  display: inline;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0px;
  top: 5px;
}

.nba {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.thenav {
  background-color: #7886a3;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.logo {
  float: left;
}


/* Style for the Nav Bar */

.thenav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.thenav ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px groove #141e38;
  position: relative;
}

.thenav ul li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 33px 10px;
}

.thenav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #47e586;
  transition: all 0.90s;
}


/*Dropdown Nav */

.thenav li ul li {
  background-color: #7886a3;
  border: 2px groove grey;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
}

.thenav li ul li a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
}

.thenav li ul li:nth-child(1) a:hover {
  background-color: #F47575;
}

.thenav li ul li:nth-child(2) a:hover {
  background-color: #f7d759;
}

.thenav li ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}

.thenav ul li ul {
  display: none;
}

.thenav li:hover ul {
  position: absolute;
}

.thenav li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}


/* End of Dropdown */

.userlogin {
  font-size: 12px;
  top: 2px;
  color: white;
}

input[type=text],
input[type=password] {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 8px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 3px 5px 3px 5px;
  color: 162354;
}


/* Stats Button */

.stat input[type=button] {
  background-color: #6cd171;
  color: blue;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 2px 2px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

.log[type=button] {
  background-color: white;
  color: #008cff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  padding: 1px 2px 2px 2px;
  position: relative;
  left: 5px;
  top: 3px;
}

.tracy {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.img-container {
  float: left;
  height: 220px;
  width: 206px;
  position: relative;
}

.fade-img {
  float: left;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-out;
  transition-delay: 3s;
}


/* Tmac Pic */

.main {
  background-color: #f7f4f4;
  margin-right: 480px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px #1f2963;
  border-radius: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.tmacLogo {
  top: 12px;
  left: 0px;
}

hr {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.main h1 {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ea5663;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #3f3c3c;
  text-shadow: 2px 3px 2px #ff2b4b;
  font-size: 30px;
  letter-spacing: 2.5px;
}

.main p {
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/* End of Main */
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1 id="box">
      <image src="nbaone.png" width="40px" height="55px" class="nba">NBA Legends</h1>
    <div class="thenav">
      <img src="nba-logo-on-wood.jpg" alt="My Layout Logo" width="100px" height="85px" class="logo">
      <nav class="top">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="http://www.nba.com">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Players</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">T-Mac <img src="tmacw.png" width="25px" height="20px" class="tmacw"></a></li>
              <li><a href="#kobesec">Kobe</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Kevin Durant</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">The Goat</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"> </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <h1>T-Mac <img src="tmacw.png" alt="TmaC" width="64px" height="44px" class="tmacLogo"></h1>
      <hr style="color:red;">
      <div class="img-container">
        <img src="tmac.jpg" alt="TmaC" width="175px" height="220px" class="tracy fade-img">
      </div>
      <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus
        PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type
        and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release. It has survived not only
        five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software
        like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type
        specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cleartwo"></div>
</body>
```

**Fixed** position means The element is positioned relative to the browser window.

You can check more about HTML element's position description on [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

Feel free to ask me if there are further questions about mine.

Comment: @rideoan what about when i want to change the "containers" width to auto so its set in the middle?